# On Excel-VBA/SQL: Login failed for user "testuser"

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, amazon-web-services

On Excel-VBA, I am trying to connect to my SQL Server on Amazon AWS/RDS (free tier). All I am getting is:

> Run-time error '-2147217843 (80040e4d)': Login failed for user
>   'testuser'.

My code:

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim StrQuery As String

ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=***sqlserver_instance***.amazonaws.com,1433;Initial Catalog=TESTDB;User ID=testuser;Password=testpassword;"

conn.Open ConnectionString

StrQuery = "SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE ThisField = '" & Sheets("ThisSheet").Range("ThisValue").Value & "'"

rst.Open StrQuery, conn

Sheets("AnotherSheet").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rst
```

I can connect, manage the DB and perform queries using SQL Server Management Studio using the same username as above.

**NOTE**: Mixed mode authentication is enabled on the SQL instance on Amazon AWS/RDS. I've also use different combination/parameters for my connection string but still the same... Also, I have a copy of the database on my local machine running SQLExpress and the code works using `Integrated Authentication=SSPI;` Tried creating a 'testuser' on my local machine with similar permissions in Amazon AWS/RDS, and I'm getting a similar error (login failed..).

Could this be a permission problem in the SQL server for the SQL user/login? What permissions does 'testuser' needs?

SQL Log reports:

> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5

BUT the username I'm using is in there and can be used to connect thru SQL Server Management Studio..

Comment: Remember that when you create a SQL user, you also have to grant the user access to the database, tables, stored procedures, ect... Maybe you are missing that part.

Comment: You could brute force it and give the user db_DataReader to the TESTDB database.

Comment: I even made it db_owner.. still the same error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

still can't figure out what is happening here, but I ended up..

1) deleting the user and the login..

2) setting the security of my SQL Server to Windows Authentication only..

3) restart the SQL Server..

4) setting the security of my SQL Server back to Mixed Mode Authentication..

5) restart again..

6) recreated the login and user.. restore permission to the database..

now it's okay..

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to connect to SQL Server using VBA you should

1. Specify in vba code the username you had created in yur DATABASE/Security/Users/your_user_name
2. Specify in vba code the password you had assigned in your INSTANCE/Security/Logins/your_login_name

Login should have this settings:

1. Login status: permission to connect to database engine: Grant
2. Login status: login: Enabled.

Instance properties:

1. Connections tab: switch on the "Allow remote connections to this server" check box.

Firewall settings:

1. Add two inbound rules for sqlbrowser.exe and  sqlservr.exe

Services.msc:

1. Ensure that SQL Server Browser is started.

Comment: Prove replacing in `Data Source=` with ip address instead of sqlserver_instance.  
Check login status isn't locked out.

Comment: for the Amazon AWS/RDS, I don't know the IP address.. Amazon only provides Endpoint "address" which works and what I use to connect thru Management Studio...

Comment: Check for your ip address in ipconfig. And then try with IPv4 address returned by ipconfig command. This is to prove with your local instance

Comment: Error... "Server does not exist or access denied"

Comment: Honestly, I don't think it's the Data Source.. SQL Log reports that the request has reached the SQL server (both on local machine and on Amazon AWS/RDS).. Just that it says (in the log): Could not find a login matching the name provided.. But the login is there and is what I used to connect thru management studio..